# Unable to LoadInput

Tags: java, awt

I am having errors when I call `LoadInput()` function...

```
private void loadInput() {
        String fn;
        FileDialog fd= new FileDialog((Frame)this.getParent(), "Load RS-274D/X file...", FileDialog.LOAD);

        fd.setVisible(true);

        fn = fd.getFile();

        if (fn != null)
            readInput(fn);

    }
```

And here is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor FileDialog(RS274X, String, int) is undefined

    at RS274X.loadInput(RS274X.java:251)
    at RS274X.actionPerformed(RS274X.java:165)
```

Comment: Please consider changing your question title.

Comment: What error does eclipse tell you? Could it be that you are running an older version of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly tells you your FileDialog class doesn't have a constructor for:

```
FileDialog(RS274X, String, int)
```

Make sure your class contains the constructor you need and that you send the right parameters when creating the object.

Comment: That's great! If an answer is the correct one, please mark it as answered.